# Loading html content based on radio values using jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im working on a script using jquery load function and im stuck with a noob issue..

I got 2 html files,

1. testload.html [Pastebin file](http://pastebin.com/kX89Chbu)
2. Name of the html file varies based on the input value given in the testload.html, but for demo purpose i have created test.html and i enter "test" in the input field for testing.

Demo test.html - [Test.html](http://pastebin.com/BGMWN1VB)

Now the problem is that when the user clicks on a radio button in the testload.html file, only the content of the div based on id should be retrieved from test.html but im getting the contents of all the div.

The ids of the div in test.html is the same as value of the individual radio buttons in testload.html

### Summary

user enters a text in input filed in testload.html (demo purpose:test)

Selects either

test1 radio => displays #1 of test.html

test2 radio => displays #2 of test.html

test3 radio => displays #3 of test.html

Problem: Im getting all the contents in one go instead of the needed content.

would love some help here..

Ty

UPDATE :

Nevermind.. a small mistake on my part. its fixed now. The problem was i missed the concatenation on my load function . and i changed the script lines to..

```
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();        
        var url = $('#page').val();
        url = url +".html #";
        $('#getcontent').load(url + test);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've come up with a easy solution for you.

```
 $('#radio1').click(function() {
       $('#res').html("");
       $('#res').load("index.html #target"); //where Target stands for the DIV inside the html file
    });


    $('#radio2').click(function() {
       $('#res').html("");
       $('#res').load("index.html #target");
    });
```

Let me know if helped you, happy scripting!

**UPDATE**

In case you want to use a var instead of specifying the proper div ID  or the html file you could use

```
 $('#res').load(htmlVar".html #"+divVar);
```

But since you're using ID's you have to use the # before the ID of the div.

For more info visit: http://api.jquery.com/load/ (Loading Page Elements).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the index.html inside the load function varies based on the user input text in the testload.html.. so i cant hardcode the filename..  and moreover there are lots of radio button so i cant write individual functions for each... :(

Comment: You can specify for instance that you want all the radio buttons $('input') and get the val of each one of them individually with $(this) inside the click function.

Comment: You can specify the html file through a variable, just do .load(varHere+".html #"+divVar); for example.

Comment: Yes i figured that out long back and completed the script as well. Please find the edited post.

Comment: Edited the answer for the specific question!

Answer (score 1):

see:Loading Page Fragments in http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

Comment: kindly read the full post .. as i said the name of the html file varies and cant be hardcoded.